# How to split column to two different columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the dataframe `df`:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [year_artist: string, count: bigint]
```

`df.show()` returns:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|         year_artist|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|    1945_Dick Haymes|    5|
|1949_Ivory Joe Hu...|    1|
|     1955_Tex Ritter|    1|
```

I need to split the first column into two separate parts, year and artist.
I am thinking of something like this: [Spark map dataframe using the dataframe's schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485536/spark-map-dataframe-using-the-dataframes-schema).

However, the following does not work in my realization:

```
df.rdd.map(row => (row(0).getAs[String].split("_")(0), row(0).getAs[String].split("_")(1)))
```

Maybe there is a way to make it without converting to RDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example use `regexp_extract`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

df.select(
  regexp_extract($"year_artist", "^(\\d{4})_(.*)", 1).alias("year"),
  regexp_extract($"year_artist", "^(\\d{4})_(.*)", 2).alias("artist")
)
```

or `split`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

df.select(
  split($"year_artist", "_")(0).alias("year"),
  split($"year_artist", "_")(1).alias("artist")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `split` (that looks pretty similar to the other answer).

```
val solution = artists.
  withColumn("nested", split($"year_artist", "_")).
  select($"nested"(0) as "year", $"nested"(1) as "artist")
scala> solution.show
+----+---------------+
|year|         artist|
+----+---------------+
|1945|    Dick Haymes|
|1949|Ivory Joe Hu...|
|1955|     Tex Ritter|
+----+---------------+
```

You could do similar with `map` operator.

```
val solution = artists.
  select("year_artist").  // assume you want only one column to work with
  as[String].             // personally I don't like Rows so make them Strings
  map { year_artist => year_artist.split("_") }.      // do the hard work using Scala
  map { case Array(year, artist) => (year, artist) }. // assume there are only two fields
  toDF("year", "artist")
scala> solution.show
+----+---------------+
|year|         artist|
+----+---------------+
|1945|    Dick Haymes|
|1949|Ivory Joe Hu...|
|1955|     Tex Ritter|
+----+---------------+
```